# DrawerLayout Over Keyboard

Tags: android, android-layout, android-softkeyboard, drawerlayout

I have a `DrawerLayout` that I use as Sliding Menu, currently i use the `InputMethodManager` to close the keyboard when the `DrawerLayout` is shown

```
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();

            // Hide Soft-Keyboard
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) MainActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(drawerView.getApplicationWindowToken(), 0);


        }
```

Is there anyway to keep the soft-keyboard open and show the `DrawerLayout` on top of it? so when the drawer layout is closed, the activity/soft-keyboard is still at the same state?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is not possible.. but you can try..there may be a way.. but my idea is hide and show the keyboard when drawer open and close that may be possible rather than your idea..

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
((InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)).toggleSoftInput
                (InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
```

Comment: I have no problems showing/hiding the keyboard, what i'm trying is to display the DrawerLayout on top of it. so the soft-keyboard is dimmed with the Activity when the DrawerLayout is displayed.